# Alternative getpwuid_r during compile throught Android NDK

Tags: android, android-ndk

During compile throught Android NDK i get error

```
... GitHub/util-linux-2.26.1/libmount/src/utils.c:654: error: undefined reference to 'getpwuid_r'
```

What can replace the [getpwuid_r](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getpwuid_r)? What the alternative, or something ?

Answer (score 1):

There is no getpwuid_r implementation in bionic libc in Android platforms below 19.
Just remove the call off the code.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem when compiling libuv for android. Upgrading the API level from 15 to 21 resolved my issue.